# which system memory is used when c# win application is running through network?

Tags: c#, networking, remote-desktop

My question is :

Which system memory is being used by the c# windows form, when it is running on the network through remote desktop when they are connected by LAN. The server memory or the client memory?

I need to know this because i want to store the login details of the users that are presently working on the application both from server end and the client end, in a public class. Basically, performing some sort of session management in windows form.

The OS for both the client and server is : WINDOWS SEVER 2003 (that means the sever is not logged off when the client connects remotely to it, it works normal, if i'am right).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If via remote desktop, then everythig is at the server, except for the RDP client (typically mstsc.exe).

Comment: Okay, i got. 

      But I want to make sessions for each users in a Remote Destop Access for the c# windows Application for displaying name and fetching their database entries.
How can i achieve this..?


            I can achieve this by updating the active_state=1 in database for the user and checking the active_state, but if more user are logged in from RDP Client,

      then HOW WILL I DIFFERENTIATE THEM ?

Answer (score 3):

RDP only transfers an image of the screen. All of your application runs in the server's memory. If you want a client - server architecture, you need to divide your application into a client part and a server part.